# Which is more efficient filter query in django and why?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

1 : `Model1.object.filter(column1="XYZ").filter(column2="ABC")`

2 : `Model1.object.filter(column1="XYX", column2="ABC")`

Among these two, which is more efficient in terms of time taken as well as number of db calls?

Comment: Both will produce the *same* query, so there is no difference in efficiency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Among these two, which is more efficient in terms of time taken as well as number of db calls?

Both will produce the *same* query, unless `column1` is a one-to-many or a many-to-many field, but then it is not a column of the model object. Both will produce a query that looks like:

```
SELECT appname_model1.*
FROM appname_model1
WHERE column1 = "XYZ" AND column2 = "ABC"
```

The second item will likely be slightly more efficient, since then it will evaluate two calls to the filter method, but this is only a matter of a few CPU cycles.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [QuerySet API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api) to see the actual sql query that are produced:

```py
print(Model1.object.filter(column1="XYZ").filter(column2="ABC").query)

print(Model1.object.filter(column1="XYX", column2="ABC").query)
```

You'll find that the queries are the same.